# using gdb to debug a interactive program that reads input from stdin

Tags: c, gdb, pthreads

I'm writing a client/server program in C.

My client has a thread reading input from stdin, it's just a while(1) loop to read input from stdin. Whenever it reads a line, it deliver it to another thread that handles message parsing and framing.

As I enter gdb, the command line is occupied by gdb prompt and I can no longer input lines into stdin.

Is there a way to do it? (I don't want to redirect stdin to an input file because I've tried this method and it didn't work)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run your program in one terminal and attach to it from gdb in another terminal.

To attach to a running program, find the process ID (PID) of the program you want to attach to, then execute `gdb <executable> <PID>`.

Comment: how to attach a process to gdb?

Comment: What if I want to debug program startup?

Comment: @zanyman that command will attach directly your process. It required root permission in my try.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Jonathan Reinhart's answer, here is a oneliner to attach to a running program by name:

```
gdb -p $(pgrep <executable-name>)
```

Comment: This works if there is only one running instance of `<executable-name>`.

Answer (score 0):

As a clarification you don't need the executable name if you do know the process id of the program. This will allow you to attach a program directly.

```
gdb -p PID
```

Comment: This will work, but I don't think GDB will know where to find the executable in order to access the symbols and debug info.